# Server access kept blocked until the ghost script completes

Tags: php, ghostscript, postscript

I'm new to ghostscript and using it to compress PDF files. I'm using the below script for this :

> 'gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite
> -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=66 -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=66 -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Subsample -dMonoImageResolution=66 -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf';

First the script takes too long to execute. 
Also the main issue is, Other pages of the server kept blocked. 

Is it right? I mean, does this happens generally that other location of the server kept blocked.

Can anyone suggest me better way to handle this where I have control of the quality of the compressed pdf.
For example : How can I achieve 80%, 50%, 30% compression from original file.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this related to `php`?

Comment: I'm using this in php, that's why added that tag.

Comment: Are you running the `gs` command synchronously?

Comment: I don't know what that mean, I'm new to gs. Just got a GS online and using it.